# SQL - Identify which strings in Column belong to the same group of values

Tags: sql, string-comparison, rowcount

I have the following column in our of my tables in MSDB, which listed file names of files imported into the scrubber. In the process of loading the files, sometimes the files are so big that we break them into multiple files and append digits (starting with 1) before the extension (in our login extension = the file name that comes after very last dot). This is a representation of that column:

> **File Name**
> abracadabra1.wav
> abracadabra2.wav
> abracadabra3.wav
> bananas24125.mp3
> orange2.mp3
> strawberry.wav1.mov
> strawberry.wav2.mov
> raspeberry.custom

My objective is to come up with a 2nd column which through various analysis would look at first column, and derive the name of the original file (before the split). My desired outcome is as follows:

> **File Name**          |             **Original File Name**
> abracadabra1.wav       |             abracadabra.wav
> abracadabra2.wav       |             abracadabra.wav
> abracadabra3.wav       |             abracadabra.wav
> bananas24125.mp3       |             bananas24125.mp3
> orange2.mp3            |             orange2.mp3
> strawberry.wav1.mov    |             strawberry.wav.mov
> strawberry.wav2.mov    |             strawberry.wav.mov
> raspeberry.custom      |             respberry.custom

I'm hesitant to put my code in here because (1) I didn't get to a point where I can say it would lead to solving this, and (2) I've been experimenting with using various functions like lag() and difference() and I feel like I might be getting off track.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What happened to `bananas24125.mp3` and `orange2.mp3` ? Why their original names didn't change in your expected result?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 those 2 are an example of files that weren't big enough to be split. They are included to show the complexity of the query that I'm trying to write - sometimes will names will end in digits, but not because they got split, but because it was their original name.

Comment: Do you mind also adding this to the actual question which will be useful to others ?

Comment: Which database you are using and which version ?

Comment: Why does raspeberry.custom become respberry.custom?

Comment: Have you considered amending the loading routine's naming convention so that it uses a naming convention that it makes it obvious that the file has been split e.g. by adding a character sequence "signature" that would never occur in the normal file name? Otherwise, I assume that you're looking for sets of files with an unbroken sequence of numbers at the end of the file names always starting from 1? (And yes, you also need to confirm the database (SQL Server?).)

Comment: As mentioned above, amending the splitting procedure to include a character such as an underscore would make this a lot easier. So, strawberry would become strawberry_1 and strawberry_2. Then you can have a case statement that looks for the underscore and return the original name if not found, otherwise return everything to the left of the underscore.

Comment: @user9601310  It would, but unfortunately I don't have control over that. The product has transitioned to me from development as-is, so at this point I have to deal with remnants like these

Comment: And your database is?